# Where is Serializer on .net core ProtoBuf?

Tags: c#, .net-core, protobuf-net

I using `Protobuf` in `Dotner Core 3.1` and install this [Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Core/) on my project, but when  i write these line of codes for serializing requested object :

```
 public static byte[] ProtoSerialize<T>(T record) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, record);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

`Visual studio` can not find related name space and  got error that can not find `Serializer`,

> The name 'Serializer' does not exist in the current context

I test it on `.Net` and install related package that works but in `.Net Core` i got error.
What is related `namespece` ? what is the problem?

Comment: You should have used this package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/ It supports .NET Core. Actually both packages have same git repo, so not sure what is going on there, but this one works fine

Comment: @Nikita having multiple artifacts from the same repo is very common

Comment: @MarcGravell yes i do agree, just by the time i wrote this comment i haven't thought about that :) actually i then wrote an answer, but yours was there already

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, install the `protobuf-net` package.

`protobuf-net.Core` is not "protobuf-net on .NET Core" - rather it is "the core part of protobuf-net". `protobuf-net` takes a dependency on `protobuf-net.Core`, regardless of whether you're using .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET 5+, or something else (on .NET Standard).

- `protobuf-net` contains all of the runtime emit logic, in addition to the `Serializer` class
- `protobuf-net.Core` contains the main reader/writer logic

There are scenarios where you don't want or need the runtime emit pieces, but in your case: you do - so just change your package dependency to `protobuf-net`.

The issue of which platform you are targeting is handled by that package manager - you don't need to worry about that. It will install the correct binaries for your platform.

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious from the documentation.  I might have made the same mistake myself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean, we don't even link to or mention `protobuf-net.Core`, and in the installation instructions we only mention `protobuf-net`; I'm not sure what more I can do, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: OP probably found the package at nuget.org, saw that it was the Core version, and installed it.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for answer, its name is really misleading it takes some hour from me :( , if u didnt answer it takes me more, plz add a note on git repo to tell the points if  is it possible, thanks anyway